# How to restore a mysql database

Tags: mysql, recovery, log

I have to re-build a mysql database (some tables were truncated), Is it possible? What logs do I need?

My mysql is 5.7 running on ubuntu 18.4

Comment: I'm not an expert on MySQL, but I don't think you can restore unless you have a backup. The logs can help you move forward from a backup to the point you want to reach, but I don't think you can go back. You need to start from somewhere and apply changes. Perhaps I'm wrong, good luck.

Comment: I have the start point (table declaration and first "service-build" queryes ), all I need is to apply what is on logs (if logs are present) arriving to a consistent point

Comment: The starting point is typically a backup, not scripts for starting over. Anyway, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.7/en/recovery-from-backups.html for the steps you need to take. Please do take a full backup now before you start! And even better do this in a test environment first.

Comment: Describe what you have. Any backups? Binlogs? If yes - what timespan do they cover?
BTW, stop and writes to MySQL partition in case recovery from the partition is needed.

Comment: No backups (otherweise I'll have restored from those), my is a knowage ce 6.1.1. installation overwritten with newer version, stop writing... I can stop the VM. As logs I have only some tiny error.log.gz in /var/log/mysql/